# Intel WiFi AX200 - MSI x570 UNCLAIMED driver

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

My Intel WiFi AX200 - MSI X570 wireless network adapter recently stopped working.
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.

`uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl`

```
Linux adrian-MS-7B93 5.4.0-51-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 5 14:28:49 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    3.526169] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.648129] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:28:00.0 failed with error -110
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       logical name: enp38s0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:d8:61:bc:3a:68
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-2 ip=192.168.1.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc600000-fc61ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fc620000-fc623fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc500000-fc503fff
```

I tried adding the `Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz` `.ucode` firmware file to `/lib/firmware` from [Intel's website](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html) with no luck.

I also tried a fresh `20.04` installation. One common item between others that I see having this issue is that they also dual boot Windows. The weird thing is I used Ubuntu 20.04 for 3+ months, and then swapped back to Windows for a few days, and upon booting back up in Ubuntu it no longer works. Switched back to Windows again to verify that the device actually works, which it still does.

Comment: Is this a possible issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Excellent! Disabling Fast boot in Windows worked. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it’s working.

Comment: @AdrianElder I had the same problem and this worked for me too. Please add it as an answer and accept. It will help others to find it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by disabling Fast boot in Windows:

https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

Comment: any idea why this works?  I just had the same issue and this fixed it (I think)

Comment: I believe fastboot allows Windows to hold onto resources for faster boot times, which conflicts with other operating systems using those same resources.