# AX200 Wifi no longer available on Ubuntu 20.04 after installing Windows 10 on other partition

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers

I've successfully installed and run a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.04 for about a month without connectivity issues of wifi, bluethooth, etc.

Yesterday after installing Windows 10 on another partition on the same drive, Ubuntu no longer have a wifi adapter available.

I've tried several different solutions posted by others, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253988/intel-ax200-wifi-card-not-found-on-ubuntu-20-04), [here](https://kurkutenarayan.medium.com/fix-no-wifi-adapter-found-ubuntu-20-04-a4da2bd748c7), etc. without luck.
I've now completely erased the whole drive and reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch but the problem remains, of course trying the same solutions again.

Running `lshw -C network` prompts:

```
...
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: Wi-Fi 7 AX200
    vendor: Intel Corporation
...
```

After following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1199679/1033541) answer, running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1
```

The command `dmesg | grep iwl` prompts the following:

```
[   2.547276] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   2.676918] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:28:00.0 failed with error -110
```

My motherboard is a MSI MEG Unify 570x. Wifi Module is enabled in BIOS.

Some [suggest disabling fast-boot in windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284878/intel-wifi-ax200-msi-x570-unclaimed-driver), which is no longer an option, since it isn't installed anymore. Any suggestions what might cause this issue still?

Comment: Did you follow this method? https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10 Fast startup is certainly still a 'feature' of my fully updated Windows 10 laptop. https://i.postimg.cc/7LdWV0JQ/IMG-0618.jpg I suspect that fast startup is exactly the issue. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That's the problem, I erased my whole drive, so Windows 10 is no longer installed and therefore I cannot do this. Would it make sense to try to install it again, just so that I can disable this. I'm really out of ideas otherwise.

Comment: If you purge linux-oem-osp1 and reboot, is the `dmesg | grep iwl` the same; that is, probe failed -110?

Comment: @chili555 yes, just tried and the exact same message is prompted.

Comment: Are those the only iwlwifi messages? Nothing about firmware? If you need to post a lengthy output, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here's a longer output from where WiFi is mentioned for the first time https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5dQkwBVTpT/

Comment: Disable Windows Fast Startup feature.

Comment: Windows is no longer available as I've wiped the ssd. Do I really need to reinstall windows to fix this? Is there no other way?

Answer (score 1):

[The suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315041/ax200-wifi-no-longer-available-on-ubuntu-20-04-after-installing-windows-10-on-ot#comment2238770_1315041) to disable the fast startup of the Windows 10 worked for me. The only question that is in my mind now is why and how did Windows hijack my wireless card? =)